# How to send POST request to API with signup form without backend

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, api

I'm trying to figure out how to connect my signup to `sender.net` API so when someone fills out the form it will be added to my subscriber list. Sender.net provided me with this information to help:

1. API is implemented through `HTTP` protocool, using `POST`. Responses are returned in [json](/questions/tagged/json).
2. All API requested shall be directed at http://app.sneder.net/api/api.
3. Request data must be encoded in [json](/questions/tagged/json), in `POST` parameter named data.

I wrote this code but nothing appears on my subscriber list, please see below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>test with sender</title>
</head>

<body>

  <h1>This is to test sender.net API "POST" </h1>

  <form>
    <input type="text" name="Fname" placeholder="first name">
    <input type="text" name="Lname" placeholder="last name">
    <input type="email" name="Email" placeholder="email address">
    <button type="submit" onclick="JSONTest()"> Let the Post req begin! 
            </button>
  </form>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    JSONTest = function() {
      $.ajax({
        url: "https://app.sender.net/api/",
        method: "POST",
        datatype: "JSON",
        data: {
          method: "listSubscribe",
          params: {
            api_key: "my key number",
            list_id: "my id number",
            emails: ["Email", "Fname", "Lname"],
            update_existing: true
          }
        }
      });
    };
  </script>

  <!-- Jquery -->
  <script src="vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Check the browser console (F12).
Maybe you get a "cross domain" error.

Comment: Change the button `type` to "button", ie `<button type="button"...`. When you hit it currently, it will submit the form normally

Comment: Also, your `<script src="vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>` should come **before** your other `<script>` tag

Comment: And one more, sender.net does not appear to allow cross-origin requests. What you're trying to do will not be possible without involving a CORS proxy.

Comment: Thanks a lot made changes based on your suggestions - at least I see movement in the console now - It says, failed to load the API: No "access-control-allow-origin" header is present on the requested API/email/fname.... Origin "null" is there not allowed access. - So I guess cause I got no CORS, will add it in.

Answer (score 1):

```
<head>
    <title>test with sender</title>
</head>

<body>

    <h1>This is to test sender.net API "POST" </h1>

    <form>
        <input type="text" name="Fname" placeholder="first name">
        <input type="text" name="Lname" placeholder="last name">
        <input type="email" name="Email" placeholder="email address">
        <button type="button" onclick="JSONTest()"> Let the Post req begin! 
        </button>
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    JSONTest = function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "https://app.sender.net/api/",
            method: "POST",
            datatype: "JSON",
            data: {
                method: "listSubscribe",
                params: {
                    api_key: "my key number",
                    list_id: "my id number",
                    emails: ["Email", "Fname", "Lname"],
                    update_existing: true
                }
            },
            success : function(response) {
                console.log(response); // Feel free to Use debugger 

            }
        });
    };
    </script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I added it in but nothing changes. Interestingly in the console when I submit, it briefly shows undefined and then disappears quickly.

Comment: What is getting printed in log?

Comment: that is the strange thing, nothing.

Comment: Ok, are you getting any error in console? Is it just reloading the page as you have mentioned button type submit?

Comment: No error in console. Right, so when I submit just reloads the page.

Comment: I have edited the answer, please go through.